# I am not able to generate a cucumber report on Jenkins

Tags: selenium, jenkins, cucumber, report

I have add cucumber report in post build action but I am keep getting the same error.
Here is the error that I am getting

```
net.masterthought.cucumber.ValidationException: File '/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/HE_HQ_Automaton/builds/111/cucumber-html-reports/.cache/target/cucumber-reports/CucumberTestReport.json' is not a valid Cucumber report!
    at net.masterthought.cucumber.ReportParser.parseForFeature(ReportParser.java:104)
    at net.masterthought.cucumber.ReportParser.parseJsonFiles(ReportParser.java:72)
    at net.masterthought.cucumber.ReportBuilder.generateReports(ReportBuilder.java:97)
    at net.masterthought.jenkins.CucumberReportPublisher.generateReport(CucumberReportPublisher.java:563)
    at net.masterthought.jenkins.CucumberReportPublisher.perform(CucumberReportPublisher.java:434)
    at jenkins.tasks.SimpleBuildStep.perform(SimpleBuildStep.java:123)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.perform(BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.java:79)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:814)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:763)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.post2(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1072)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:707)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1921)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:543)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:101)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:442)
```

I did check and make sure that I have correct plugin and I was expecting to get a report but not successful so far. I was able to generate a report last week but not now anymore

Comment: Apology in advance if my question is not clear enough. I am more than happy to provide more content about the issue if you want me to. Thanks again.

Comment: It says the `CucumberTestReport.json`  is not valid you should look at it and see what is wrong.

Comment: I have looked CucumberTestReport.json and I don't see any issue with that. I am able to generate a extend report on local but not a cucumber report o Jenkins.